# Not able to access HTTPS link. Getting ssl connection error?

Tags: linux, apache, apache2

As i have enabled default-ssl site in my ubuntu linux server. When I load the site with Google Chrome I get this error:

> SSL connection error
>   Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
>   Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

With Firefox:

> SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
>   (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

As i have check log file of apache2. Which say **suhosin-path mod_ssl**

```
[Fri Apr 04 16:29:33 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.14.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

FYI, 
**when i run command "apachectl -S" i get this error**

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
Syntax OK
```

**if i run "apachectl configtest"**

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
Syntax OK
```

**EDIT 1**
I am getting below error also

```
Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x01
```

Please help me.

Comment: In chrome It says: SSL connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

And In firefox : 
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Here is the solution.

As my domain (example.com) is configured for port forwarding and It was mapping to my Local server 
To Access my local server through example.com
It was like this:

```
http://example.com:1234/project_name
```

and i was configuring my local server for https
which was accessible as

```
https://192.168.**.***/project_name
```

But it was giving error **(Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x01)** for below url

```
https://example.com:1234/project_name
```

Because example.com was not configured for ssl.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting up an HTTP server on port 443, e.g on a port usually used for HTTPS (HTTP wrapped inside a SSL connection). The `Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x01` you get on the server side is the start of the SSL handshake of from the client. And because the client does not get the expected answer back from the server it complains.

I don't know what your intention with this setup is, but

- if you want to use only HTTP keep the listener on port 80 and remove the one on port 443
- if you want to set up HTTPS you need certificates etc (there is enough documentation out there)